# SQL Server Exception Handling

Tags: sql-server, exception

I am trying to understand what exactly is meant by **TRY-CATCH** *does not catch compilation errors that occur in the same scope*.

I am currently trying to set up exception handling in SQL Server and I came across this statement a couple of times, but don't quite understand what it means. I notice that if I have an **INSERT** statement, the exception handling works for **PRIMARY KEY constraint** errors, but it doesn't seem to work for **INSERT** statements that include an extra column.

Comment: Try and catch will catch all exceptions, assuming you have it set up right.  Please post some of your code so we can see why it's not catching the column error insert. The compilation error might be referring to your catches not being in the right order

Comment: Are you expecting it to catch syntax errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it doesn't seem to work for INSERT statements that include an extra column.

Right, because TRY-CATCH does not catch compilation errors that occur in the same scope.

If your compilation error happens in a nested scope, your catch block will run.

Here's a simple example of the behavior:

```
create table t(id int)
go
begin try
   insert into t(id) values (1,2)
end try
begin catch

  select concat('catch block ', error_message())
end catch
go
begin try
   exec ('insert into t(id) values (1,2)');
end try
begin catch

  select concat('catch block ', error_message())
end catch
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I didn't really understand the concept of scope, but your explanation helps. Once I included the INSERT statement into the exec(....) block, the TRY-CATCH worked

Answer (score -1):

you can use **SQLEXCEPTION** handler

here is an example

```
use TEST_SERVICE ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TEST_SERVICE.migrate_data;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE migrate_data()
Block1 : BEGIN
  declare loop_emp_check int default 0;
  declare emp_name varchar(100) default null;
  declare dept_id int default 0;
  declare error_message varchar(100) default null;
  declare error_code varchar(100) default null;
  
  -- cursor for employee data
  declare emp_cursor cursor for SELECT NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID FROM TEST_SERVICE.EMPLOYEE;
  
  -- handler declaration
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET loop_emp_check = 1;

-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 error_code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, error_message = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SELECT error_code, error_message;
    ROLLBACK;
  END;
-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

  open emp_cursor;
  START TRANSACTION;
  emp_loop: loop
  
    -- fetching employee data
    fetch emp_cursor into emp_name, dept_id;
    
    -- loop termination condition
    if loop_emp_check = 1 then
    close emp_cursor;
    leave emp_loop;
    end if;
    
    -- inserting employee data
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_V1(NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID) VALUES (emp_name, dept_id);
  END LOOP emp_loop;  
  COMMIT; -- commit once all the values which are migrated
END Block1;
//
delimiter ;
```

I recently wrote a [blog](https://medium.com/p/824954009f1c) on this.

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server and asking specifically about the `TRY-CATCH` in that product. This code is for MySQL not for SQL Server and does not answer the question asked "what exactly is meant by TRY-CATCH does not catch compilation errors that occur in the same scope?"