# How do I handle exceptions in SQL properly?

Tags: sql, database, exception

I am working in Oracle SQL developer.
I got a simple database and I have to complete some error handling.

I have to change the salary of an employee who has the 'employee_id:129' to the persons salary whose name is 'Peter' in my database.

I have to handle some exceptions, like:
1,If there is no 'Peter' in my database, I have to print out the average salary of all employees

2, if there is several 'Peters' in my database, I have to print out the smallest salary of all Peters I have.

I do have 3 Peters in my database.
The employee ID 129 does exist.
I was trying to solve it as a procedure so far.

The code I wrote so far complies, but I never get the exception I am looking for...

Comment: I assume this is a homework question? Please add the code you've already written to your question, as editable text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847461/sql-server-exception-handling)